# Finding all prime implicates in k-maps

Tags: karnaugh-map

Function:  Σ a,b,c,d(2,5,6,7,8,12) + D a,b,c,d(1,10,13,15)

My attempt at solution

[image]

Prime Implicates :

- BD
- AC’D’
- A’CD’
- A’BC
- B’CD’
- AB’D’
- ABC’

Essential Prime Implicates : BD

Minimal SOP: BD + AC’D’+A’CD’

Am I including too many implicates for the prime implicates? When do I know that the prime implicate is not needed? For example the implicate A'C'D was not included because the "1" in question was already apart of an implicate that was larger (4 as opposed to 2). Is it true that I include all possible combinations of an implicate if it belongs to an implicate of the same size?

Comment: You don't need to include an implicant when you've already covered that value of 1.  For instance you wouldn't include **ABC'** because that 1 was already included in **AC'D'**, and the same with your example of **A'C'D**. Your answer looks correct

Comment: Hmm. If I don't have to include a PI for 1's already covered then do I need B'CD'? Or were you referring to Essential PI's? A program told me AC'D is a PI so now I am really confused

Comment: How did you drawed it?